# Tools to search strings in C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the SQL equivalent of `LIKE '%text to search%'` in C#. Really just a small text searching engine I can use to check if a string is a match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you take a look at [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28VS.71%29.aspx)? Although, for simpler cases, you are just fine using methods like [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx).

Comment: *Smacks forehead - I have no idea String.Contains was not my first thought. Thanks